# can't understand a question about finding general solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

there is a question in my homework: "there is two equation systems in three variables,(O) is homogeneous and (M) is non homogeneous: 
[image]

its known that (1,0,1) and (-1,1,1) are solutions for (O) and that (2,-3,1) is a solution for (M). find the general solution for (O) and (M)."

i am very new to linear algebra and the teacher didn't explained much on the subject and i can't understand this question. can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution is $$\pmatrix{2\\-3\\1}+s\pmatrix{1\\0\\1}+t\pmatrix{-1\\1\\1}$$, where $s$ and $t$ are real numbers.

The general solution of an inhomogenous system of linear equations is equal to the sum of the general solution of the corresponding homogenous system and some special solution of the inhomogenous system.

Every linear combination of solutions of the homogenous system is again a solution of the homogenous system.

Comment: what is a "special solution"?.

Comment: Any particular solution

Comment: In this case, $(2/-3/1)$. It is just one solution of the given (in general inhomogenous) system. It does not matter which one you choose.

Comment: and you mean that when the general solution of a homogeneous system is added to the general solution of another system it doesn't change its value?.

Comment: No, we have the inhomogenous system, we need ONE solution of this system. And we have the  CORRESPONDING homogenous system, we need the general solution of this system. The sum of both is the GENERAL solution of the INHOMOGENOUS system.

Answer (score 0):

The homogeneous system (O) has two linearly independent solution, hence the space $S$ of  solutions has dimension $\ge 2$.

The inhomogeneous system has at least one solution, $(2,-3,1)$, hence the set of solutions is the affine subspace:
$$(2,-3,1)+S=\begin{cases}(2+t-u,-3+u,1+t+u),\quad t,u\in\mathbf R&\text{if}\enspace \dim S=2,\\ \mathbf R^3\qquad\text{if}\enspace \dim S=3.\end{cases}$$